# Disabling Gatekeeper is unfruitful : still get the prevention

Tags: applications, security, mojave, gatekeeper

I found out googling around that while the option to manually allow apps from anywhere to be opened directly was removed : https://www.techjunkie.com/gatekeeper-macos-sierra/

you could still use a terminal command to make the same thing happen :

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

yet I ran it, then rebooted and tried running the app again, and I still got the same message preventing me from opening the app and forcing me to open it from the "Security&Privacy" menu in settings.

In a context of multiple back to back tests of my app on a fresh reinstall of mac & also new accounts, I cannot put up with it anymore I'd like to be able to do something to the mac when I use one of it's accounts for the first time (or better yet something GLOBAL that applies to ALL accounts) and not have to think about it anymore.

as per demand :

```
command$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.

command$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.5
BuildVersion:   18F132
```

Comment: What's the OS version and build per `sw_vers` and `csrutil status` when you restart after running `spctl` from the internet recovery / recovery HD?

Comment: You do know you can open the app without going to Security & Privacy, right? You can just control+click the app and choose "Open".

Comment: @bmike sorry I don't understand how to get that info, could you run me through it? I added the output for `csrutil status` but apparently you only want it's output after another command has been run plus reboot? but `sv_vers` is not a recognised command and `spctl` is missing args. I added the mojave tag. it's mac 10.14.5

Comment: @TJLuoma yeah I do. like I said the goal here is to attain minimum hassle. these two extra actions plus keystrokes, times the number of times I'd have to do it per day is not a solution for me.

Comment: @bmikeam I supposed to do this : https://ss64.com/osx/csrutil.html (the examples section) ?